# passing time stamp value to REST API

Tags: rest

I have a REST API which ends with /v2/users/ for corresponding url http://255.02.125.901:9087

How can I pass a timestamp to the API say, today morning 8 am, so that i can get all updates after it. Please  The response will be json object.

Regards,

Comment: what is the language ?

Comment: hi it is auth_timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified that you want to retrieve all updates since a certain point in time. A timestamp is just some arbitrary metadata and should not be passed within the actual payload of the request. Furhtemore, as `GET` prevents entity bodies, you need to fallback to `POST` which removes the ability to cache the response and moreover has a completly different semantic than a retrieval! Therefore I highly recommend NOT sending the timestamp within a JSON body to the service.

Instead use a [conditional GET request](https://ruturajv.wordpress.com/2005/12/27/conditional-get-request/). This will also tell you that the timestamp to pass to the service will need to be in a format specified in [Date and Time Specification section of RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html).

If you don't want to use conditional `GET` requests, try passing the metadata with the URI f.e. like this:

```
/v2/users?year=2015&month=7&day=10&hour=11&minutes=9&seconds=10&timezone=CET
```

If you want you can allso encapsulate the timestamp within a path-parameter. Though, I would recomment using conditional get-requests

Answer (score 7):

Format the timestamp as [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```
{
    "timestamp": "2015-07-05T22:16:18Z"
}
```

Every programming language will have a function or library available to parse this format into a date/time object.

Comment: are you saying this way we must send timestamp? Are you sure if its GET/POST request?

Comment: @OpenJDK I don't understand you comment. When doing REST using JSON (as mentioned in the question) it is a good idea to follow standards. ISO 8601 is the standard to represent timestamps.

Comment: And may be unrelated, but is sending timestamp to UI is always required ?

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of passing the number of seconds since 1970.  That simplifies the URL and eliminates time zone as an issue.

But since humans sometimes have to come up with that number, might be good to display the actual time complete with zone in the response and when logging the request.